# What is the subgroup of $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ which preserves the discriminant?

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, discriminant

$\DeclareMathOperator{\SL}{\operatorname{SL}}$Let $\mathcal{P}_{n-1}$ be the space of complex polynomials in one variable, say $z$, of degree at most $n-1$. As a complex vector space, it is clearly $n$-dimensional. Consider the basis $1$, $z,\ldots,z^{n-1}$ of $\mathcal{P}_{n-1}$. This allows us to identify $\mathcal{P}_{n-1}$ with $\mathbb{C}^n$.

The complex Lie group $\SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ acts on $\mathbb{C}^n$, and thus, via our identification, it acts on $\mathcal{P}_{n-1}$. The discriminant is a homogeneous polynomial on $\mathcal{P}_{n-1}$ of degree $2n-2$.

My question can now be formulated. What is the subgroup of $\SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ which preserves the discriminant (using our identification of $\mathcal{P}_{n-1}$ with $\mathbb{C}^n$)? I have a feeling it is the image of $\SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ under a principal homomorphism from $\SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ to $\SL(n,\mathbb{C})$.

More specifically, $\SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ acts simultaneously on all linear factors of a polynomial of degree $n-1$, and this action preserves the discriminant. I think these are all "projective" transformations which preserve the discriminant, but I am not sure how to show that. Edit: I should really write that I think these are all transformations in $\SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ which preserve the discriminant (see the remark by @NoamD.Elkies below).

Edit 2: here is a conceptual proof for polynomials of degree at most $2$ (i.e. for $n=3$ using my notation). Let $L$ be the map on $\mathbb{C}P^2$ induced by some element $g \in \SL(3,\mathbb{C})$ which preserves the discriminant of quadratic polynomials. Note that we can think of $\mathbb{C}P^2$ as the set of unordered pairs of points on $\mathbb{C}P^1$ (namely the roots of the corresponding polynomial, viewed up to scaling). Note also that polynomials of vanishing discriminant correspond to an unordered pair of coinciding points on $\mathbb{C}P^1$.

Let $f$ be the holomorphic map from $\mathbb{C}P^1$ to $\mathbb{C}P^1$ obtained essentially by restricting $L$ to coinciding pairs of points on $\mathbb{C}P^1$, in turn corresponding to the vanishing locus of the discriminant. Note that $f$ induces a holomorphic map $\tilde{f}$ on the set of unordered pairs of points on $\mathbb{C}P^1$, and thus on $\mathbb{C}P^2$.

Moreover, $\tilde{f}$ and $L$ agree on the conic in $\mathbb{C}P^1$ coinciding to the vanishing locus of the discriminant, and thus they must be equal, since they are two linear isomorphism maps from $\mathbb{C}P^2$ to itself which agree on a conic in $\mathbb{C}P^2$.

We have thus shown the claim for $n=3$. I am hoping this can be generalized to higher $n$'s. I think it is doable.

Edit 3: the previous argument can be generalized using an additional hypothesis, that the element $g \in \SL(n,\mathbb{C})$ not only preserves the discriminant, but also maps any polynomial with a single root of multiplicity $n-1$ to a polynomial with a single root of multiplicity $n-1$. Under this additional hypothesis, essentially the same argument proves that $L$, which is the map on $\mathbb{C}P^{n-1}$ induced by $g$, is induced by some holomorphic automorphism of $\mathbb{C}P^1$, and thus by some element of $\SL(2,\mathbb{C})$. But is it necessary to make this assumption? Is my conclusion false without it? Or is it perhaps the case that this hypothesis can be proved?

Comment: What is the principal homomorphism?  One corresponding to a regular nilpotent element?

Comment: Yes. And it is unique in this case up to conjugation by an element in $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: That's almost right, but there are more scalars,
as you can already see for $n=3$: the image of ${\rm SL}_2$ is
the special orthogonal group ${\rm SO}_3$ of the quadratic form $b^2-4ac$,
but the full automorphism group is the full orthogonal group ${\rm O}_3$.

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies, isn't it $\operatorname{SO}(2, 1)$?  (EDIT:  Oh, sorry, complex.)

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies, do you know what happens for higher degrees please? (By the way, I restricted my Lie group to be $SL(n,\mathbb{C})$, so $O(3,\mathbb{C}) \cap SL(3,\mathbb{C})$ is $SO(3,\mathbb{C})$).

Comment: With a computer you could easily compute the Lie algebra of the group you're looking for, for small values of $n$, and in particular its dimension.

Comment: @YCor, this is interesting. Which software could I use for that please?

Comment: You need to convert into a system of linear equations, to solve it any mathematical software would do the job. And computing these equations, essentially only involve computing partial derivatives of the discriminant.

Comment: View $\mathcal{P}_{n}$ as the space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ in 2 variables. Let $\Delta _p\subset \mathcal{P}_p$ be the locus of polynomials with one linear factor of multiplicity $\geq p$. It should be well-known that the singular locus of $\Delta _p$ is $\Delta _{p+1}$. This implies that your group preserves $\Delta _n$; up to homotheties, this is the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^{n}$ preserving $\mathbb{P}^1$ embedded by the $n$-th Veronese embedding. This is easily seen to be $\operatorname{PGL}(2,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: @abx, very nice argument. It answers my question, so could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the request of the OP, I post my comment as an answer. View $\mathcal{P}_n$  as the space of homogeneous polynomials of degree $n$ in 2 variables. Let $\Delta _p\subset \mathcal{P}_n$ be the locus of polynomials with one linear factor of multiplicity $\geq p$. One can show that
the singular locus of $\Delta _p$ is $\Delta _{p+1}$. Therefore the subgroup $G$ of $\operatorname{GL}(\mathcal{P}_n) $ preserving the discriminant hypersurface $\Delta _2$ preserves $\Delta _n$. Now the image of $\Delta _n$ in $\mathbb{P}(\mathcal{P}_n)\cong \mathbb{P}^n$ is a rational normal curve, that is, the image of the $n$-th  Veronese embedding $V_n:\mathbb{P}^1\hookrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$. Thus up to homotheties,  $G$ is  the group of automorphisms of $\mathbb{P}^n$ preserving
$V_n(\mathbb{P}^1)$, which maps isomorphically to $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb{P}^1)=\operatorname{PGL}(2,\mathbb{C})  $.

Comment: In $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbf{C})$ there are many copies of $\mathrm{(P)SL}(2,\mathbf{C})$ (finitely many up to conjugation), and in particular the irreducible one, which is unique up to conjugacy. Is this the irreducible copy? If $n$ is even, this is a copy of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbf{C})$ rather than $\mathrm{PGL}(2,\mathbf{C})$.

Comment: @YCor: I am using the projective set-up because I think it is more classical, you just have to pull back to $\operatorname{GL}(n)$. What you get
 is the standard representation of $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{C}) $ in $\operatorname{Sym}^n \mathbb{C}^2$. Indeed if $n$ is even the corresponding homomorphism $\operatorname{SL}(2)\rightarrow \operatorname{SL}(n)  $ factors through $\operatorname{PGL}(2)$.

Comment: This answer is great. I just wanted to point out an even shorter argument, along similar lines, provided to me by I.D. (I am not sure if he wants to be named or not). It is based on the statement that the discriminant hypersurface is the dual hypersurface of the Veronese curve. So a projective automorphism which leaves the discriminant hypersurface invariant also must preserve the Veronese curve. This is really neat.

Comment: Just a short complement: the description of singular loci for coincident root loci and in particular the discriminant is given in Thm 5.4 of the article by Chipalkatti https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0110224

Comment: For the result about duality, for coincident root loci, see Corollary 2.7 of this article by Lee and Sturmfels https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.00202